# Associativity of concatenation of closed curves from $I$ to some topological spaces $X$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples, fundamental-groups, associativity

I'm looking for  some example of closed curve such that $f*(g*h)=(f*g)*h,$ in some topological space $X$.

I tried to use $X$ like the Sierpinski space, but I can't find such closed curve.

Comment: Please clarify what you want to prove. To show that associativity holds, or fails? An example would not prove that it holds. Also, are the curves considered equal up to homotopy?

Comment: f(t) = g(t) = h(t) = x for all t should do

Comment: I know that the associativity fail in general and I know that one example don´t show nothing, But I need one example where this holds, like a function no up homotopy, because for one example of this is only necesary think in a topological spaces where the product is homotopy to the concatenation and the product y associative.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on your definition of $f * g$ (indeed for Moore loops *every* triplet satisfies the equation), but let's use the most common definition: for $f, g : [0,1] \to X$,
$$(f*g)(t) := \begin{cases}
f(2t), & 0 \le t \le \frac{1}{2}; \\
g(2t-1), & \frac{1}{2} \le t \le 1.
\end{cases}$$

If you allow your space to not be Hausdorff, weird things can happen. Let $X = \{0,1\}$ with the indiscrete topology (ie. the only open sets are $\emptyset$ and $X$). Let $f = g = h = \gamma : I \to X$ be defined by
$$\gamma(t) = \begin{cases}
1, & t = p/2^n \text{ for some } p \in \mathbb{N}; \\
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$

This is continuous because every map to an indiscrete space is continuous. And you can check directly from the definition that $\gamma*(\gamma*\gamma) = (\gamma*\gamma)*\gamma$ (simply because $x$ is a dyadic number iff $2x$ is iff $2x - 1$ is), but of course $\gamma$ isn't the constant loop.

---

However, when your space is Hausdorff, the situation is considerably simpler. The condition $(f*g)*h = f*(g*h)$ pointwise (ie. you literally have $((f*g)*h)(t) = (f*(g*h))(t)$ for all $t$) is equivalent to $$f = f*g \text{ and } h = g*h,$$ just by inspecting the definition.

So when is it possible to have $f = f*g$ for example? Let $t \in [0,1]$, then:
$$f\left(\frac{t+1}{2}\right) = (f * g)\left(\frac{t+1}{2}\right) = g(t).$$

But then $f = f*g = (f*g)*g$, so $f\left(\frac{t+1}{4}\right)$ is again equal to $g(t)$. Here is a picture if it can help:

[image]

By induction, $$g(t) = f\left(\frac{t+1}{2^n}\right),$$ which converges to $f(0)$ (remember that $f$ is continuous). Thus $g$ is the constant loop, **if your space is Hausdorff** (because a sequence can only have one limit). Now using again the same trick $f = f*g = (f*g)*g = \dots$, you can deduce that $f(t) = f(1)$ for all $t$ (divide $[0,1]$ into intervals of the type $(1/2^{n+1}, 1/2^n]$). Thus $f$ is the constant loop too.

The same argument (with minor modifications) shows that $h = g*h \implies h = \text{cst}$. In conclusion, the only triplet of loops $(f,g,h)$ such that $f*(g*h) = (f*g)*h$ "on the nose" is the triplet $(\text{cst}, \text{cst}, \text{cst})$ of three constant loops if your space is Hausdorff.