# Homotopy/fundamental group question: Why group axioms fail when defined on paths?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Neither Munkres nor Lee in their textbooks explicitly show why (fundamental) group properties like associativity fail when defined at the level of paths but work fine for homotopy classes of paths.

Given three paths $f$, $g$, and $h$, and if they are composable, why is the following ill-defined: $f.(g.h) = (f. g).h$.

Why should we only consider $[f], [g], [h]$? What exactly goes wrong with defining it at the level of paths?

Thank you.

Comment: The associative law for paths is not "ill-defined," it is simply not true. There also isn't an identity path when dealing with "just paths." Without an identity, it is hard to have multiplicative inverses. Basically, you lose **all** of the properties of a group if you only consider paths.

Comment: At a common base point, could not we create an identity path I(x) = a?

Comment: What is $I\cdot p$ for a path $p$? Is it **exactly** the same path as $p$? If so, you'll have to tell me how you are defining $\cdot$, because the usual definition is equal to $I(2t)$ for $t\in[0,1/2]$ and $p(2t-1)$ for $t\in[1/2,1]$, so $I\cdot p\neq p$.

Comment: The constant path is not an identity path on the level of paths (and not homotopy classes thereof). Consider the path $p(t) = e^{2\pi i t}$ as a path $[0,1] \to S^1$. Then notice that $l . p$ is not the same as $p$.

Comment: Thank you for the responses. Although the function definition $I.p$ is not $p$, the image is still the same, is it not?

Comment: Image of a path is not the only thing that is important. There are several different paths with the same image. @Wulfgang

Comment: For example, if image was all that mattered, then $a\cdot b=b\cdot a$ for any paths $a,b$. And even then, what is the inverse of a path? How do you take a path $p$ with an image of more than one point, and find another path $q$ so that $p\cdot q$ has an image of one point?

Comment: I'll just preempt Ronnie Brown and point out that the relevant structure on path homotopy classes is that of a groupoid, not a group. Basically, it means you can't always multiply two elements. If you don't want to pass to homotopy, you are looking at something like an $\infty$ category, which requires carrying along a whole bunch of other structure, including the homotopy between the two associations defined above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two functions $(a\cdot b)\cdot c$ and $a\cdot(b\cdot c)$ are;

$$\begin{align}((a\cdot b)\cdot c)(t)&=\begin{cases}a(4t)&t\in[0,1/4]\\
b(4t-1)&t\in[1/4,1/2]\\
c(2t-1)&t\in[1/2,1]
\end{cases}\\
(a\cdot (b\cdot c))(t)&=\begin{cases}a(2t)&t\in[0,1/2]\\
b(4t-2)&t\in[1/2,3/4]\\
c(4t-3)&t\in[1/4,1]
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$

These two paths are rarely exactly the same.

Comment: In fact, if the space is Hausdorff then [the only case when they are the same if when all three loops are constant](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201879/associativity-of-concatenation-of-closed-curves-from-i-to-some-topological-spa). If the space is not Hausdorff then things get awry.

Answer (score 4):

Your original question was answered. The purpose of this answer is to provide a broader context to the question, and perhaps in some sense answer it differently. The problem is not so much that the group properties fail, but that taking paths instead of homotopy classes of paths is a different object, measuring different aspects of the space. Firstly, simply taking all loops $S^1\to X$ for a pointed space $X$ and taking as binary operation $f\circ g$ to be some concatenation of the two paths fails to be a group, but it is a very reasonable structure. It fails to be a group since you must choose a particular reparametrisation to obtain the concatenation, and that will fail to be associative. It will however be associative up to higher constraints which themselves will satisfy higher associativity constraints in an infinite, and quite intricate, tower. So it makes perfect sense to take the paths themselves, but you get something more complicated.

There is a very simple way to avoid some of these difficulties by considering loops to be maps $[0,a]\to X$ for all possible intervals $[0,a]$. Then a canonical concatenation of $[0,a]\to X$ and $[0,b]\to X$ is naturally given by the obvious identification of the pushout of the two intervals as $[0,a+b]$. This operation is associative and unital (the unit is the constant path $[0,0]\to X$) but lacks inverses (though there is a canonical choice for a homotopy inverse). So this is a monoid, and it holds much more information than the fundamental group. But that is precisely the problem. It's a much more complicated and larger object, so more difficult to compute. The quest is not necessarily to find a group but rather to consider the idea of homotopy, the information lost when passing to homotopy, and *see* what you get. You get a group, and that makes us very happy. There are tools to compute that group, and that makes us even a happier.

Comment: "The problem is not so much..." Well, actually, that is exactly the question at hand - why isn't this a group? The question is not "can we study this thing." We certainly can.

Comment: absolutely @ThomasAndrews I just thought it useful for OP to understand that it is not the desire to have a group that brings us to quotient by homotopy, it is the quotient that interests us. I remember as a student that the motivation for the fundamental group was presented as if we just really are looking for a group and follow our nose to do what it takes to obtain a group. This is misleading and the reason for my lengthy answer which, as you say, subsides OP's question, but, hopefully, places it in a different light.

Comment: Right, it's just rude to say "The question is not...," **negating** the OPs question. You can add information, but don't suggest that the question is invalid or not useful.

Comment: You also say that defining paths in terms of $[0,a]$ makes it a group, but I don't see the inverses there. It is a monoid, though.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews of course, a monoid. Thanks (corrected). I changed the wording of the opening phrase to better explain the purpose of this answer.