# A question about Homotopy (Michael Harris's recent book)

Tags: algebraic-topology, math-history, homotopy-theory

In the recent book "[Mathematics without Apologies: Portrait of a Problematic Vocation](https://books.google.es/books?id=UZGSBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA195&lpg=PA195&dq=sameness%20grothendieck&source=bl&ots=sMjkIZaSGE&sig=pmTxaYcjm0cX6ECvnkOXMbvYtkA&hl=pt-PT&sa=X&ved=0CDQQ6AEwAmoVChMItZXm5YaNyAIVi1gUCh3Y_AUP#v=onepage&q=sameness%20grothendieck&f=false)" by Michael Harris
there is some passage I want to call your attention on. Specifically, pages 211-212.  Could anyone here elaborate on the problem of the different steps and the time interval he refers to on the first paragraph of page 212? I mean, his formulation is pretty clear to me, I just wanted to know more about the history of the problem, the practical and theoretical solutions proposed in the field and so on.

Here you have a brief summary:

On Figure 7.5 on page 211 the homotopy which goes from the empty set sign to the infinity sign is presented. 
He then discusses the losses of information which are allowed, on the example of a soft pretzel and makes a brief reference to Voevodsky.

The crucial part, though, is the following paragraph, which I copy to you.

> But working rigorously with homotopies presents new problems. To make it a mathematical theory, we have to imagine each homotopy as a stretching /shrinking procedure that takes place in a fixed time interval, say one second. A problem is already apparent in Figure 7.5: each of the three steps is supposed to last one second, but the whole procedure is also a homotopy, and, therefore, wants to last one second. The traditional solution is to speed up the intermediate steps to make the total come out to one second. But there are (infinitely) many ways to do this, and the set of all such ways is itself a topological space: how do we choose the right one? The traditional answer is that there is no right answer: for the riddles topology was originally invented to solve, it doesn’t matter which way you choose."
>
> An then he moves on to mention in the next paragraph, how from the 60s on topologists concerned with keeping track of all the intermediate choices sought (small-f) foundations for higher category theory. He then quotes  Jacob Lurie’s development of $\infty$-categories, and so on.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In fact, this isn't a link to the pages 211-212.

Comment: You can access to pages 211-212 by scrolling down once you get to the link. That is the best I could manage thus far. I will try to get some time to type the essential parte of the text myself tonight or soon....

Comment: You know that different people get different pages access on Google Books, right?

Comment: NO, I did not know that. I will try to type the text soon.

Comment: This has a surprisingly long answer. An older theory than Lurie's that grew out of attempting to handle this and related situations is that of operads.

Comment: @Kevin Carlson. Well, try to provide the answer, even if it in several installments :) I guess the problem as such is pretty classical (maybe back to Descartes, I would assume from a philosophical standpoint).... I will be happy to learn about it form you and the others....

Comment: You might want to look into the "little $n$-cubes (or disks) operad".

Comment: @JavierArias Producing a decent sketch of the history of homotopy coherent algebra is a bit of a time investment. I can tell you that this has absolutely nothing to do with Descartes, except insofar as all of modern math does. Maybe someone else will answer this thoroughly, but what usually happens with these open-ended questions is that you have to go look around the Internet for yourself.

Comment: @JustinYoung Thanks for the reference. I will have a look at that.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I do not need a whole story, just a brief one, with the main landmarks and so on :) I found some history on the Russian wiki entry for homotopy, which mentions James Stasheff, Murray Gerstenhaber, VA Artamonov andGeorge Peter Meem, among others.....I referred to Descartes because I reminds me of his problem of the instant, which in the end has to be timeless in order to contain several innerly articulated momenta which are processes, analogous (albeit  different) to the shrinking and stretching mentioned here.....

Comment: By the way, does Daniel Quillen's Algebraic K-theory play any role in the history of the answer to the problem?

Comment: You seem to be grandly underestimating the effort needed to write down a minimally sensible answer to what you want.

Comment: If you have access to it, [What is... an operad?](http://www.ams.org/notices/200406/what-is.pdf) by Stasheff is a concise introduction to the theory of operads. The book Operads in algebra, topology and physics by Markl, Shnider and Stasheff is also good. It's a very interesting question, and I agree with @KevinCarlson that the answer would be very long. But if someone manages to write an introduction to this whole theory that fits in a math.SE answer, that could be nice.

Comment: I am eager to learn from you all. I already knew Stashef brief paper, but I am looking for something, on the one hand, more detailed and, on the ther, with more of a philosophical flair to it, if you will. I hope creating a bounty will help

Comment: Well, I guess It might be ok if people start providing chunks of the answer (as far as they are clearly distinguishable and organized)......that might help others get into it......and maybe a fine answer is achieved by glueing everything......

Comment: Thanks for the reply from Najib Idrissi. I gave him 2 points for good answer. I will wait more time to see if some further (and eventually even better) anwer come before bestowing the 50 bounty points. Right now they are for him.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic things we're looking at are *paths*, that is maps from the interval $I = [0,1]$ to some space $X$. If $X$ and $Y$ are nice enough spaces (I don't want to get bogged down in technicalities), then a homotopy between two maps $f, g : X \to Y$ is the same thing as a path $h : I \to Y^X$ such that $h(0) = f$ and $h(1) = g$, so this whole discussion applies in particular to homotopies.

When you've got two paths $\alpha, \beta : I \to X$ such that the end of $\alpha$ coincides with the beginning of $\beta$ (IOW, $\alpha(1) = \beta(0)$), then you can *concatenate* the paths $\alpha$ and $\beta$, and obtain a new path $\beta \alpha$ (written like function composition). The traditional way of doing this is to define:
$$(\beta\alpha)(t) = \begin{cases}
\alpha(2t) & 0 \le t \le \frac{1}{2} \\
\beta(2t-1) & \frac{1}{2} \le t \le 1
\end{cases}$$
Since $\alpha(1) = \beta(0)$, this is well defined and continuous at $t = 1/2$. Basically, you go through the path $\alpha$ at double speed, then through the path $\beta$ at double speed.

---

From now on, for simplicity, I will consider **loops**. Fix some base point $x_0 \in X$, and define
$$\Omega X = \{ \gamma : I \to X \mid \gamma(0) = \gamma(1) = x_0 \},$$
in other words paths that start and end at $x_0$. This avoids the discussion about "$\alpha(1) = \beta(0)$", because you can concatenate all loops (they all start and end at the same point), and it's enough to have a general idea of the theory.

---

But there is a problem now. Suppose you have three loops $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \Omega X$. You want to concatenate them. You have basically two ways of doing that:

- first concatenate $\alpha$ and $\beta$, then concatenate the result with $\gamma$, to get $\gamma(\beta\alpha)$;
- or first concatenate $\beta$ and $\gamma$, and then concatenate $\alpha$ with the result to obtain $(\gamma\beta)\alpha$.

Then, [unless all three paths are constant (if your space is Hausdorff)](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1201879/10014),
$$\gamma(\beta\alpha) \neq (\gamma\beta)\alpha \quad(!)$$
Concatenation isn't, in general, associative. The two loops $\gamma(\beta\alpha)$ and $(\gamma\beta)\alpha$ are homotopic, but not equal. There is also no "unit loop" $e$, such that if you concatenate it with another loop you get the original loop (i.e. $e \gamma = \gamma$ or $\gamma e = \gamma$).

So how do we solve this? One possible solution is *Moore loops*. Instead of requiring all paths to take "one second" ($I = [0,1]$) to complete, you consider more general paths of the form $\alpha : [0,T] \to X$ where $T \ge 0$ (s.t. $\alpha(0) = \alpha(T) = x_0$). Then given $\alpha : [0,T] \to X$ and $\beta : [0,T'] \to X$ that start and end at $x_0$, you can obtain a new path $\beta\alpha : [0,T+T'] \to X$ defined by
$$(\beta\alpha)(t) = \begin{cases}
\alpha(t) & 0 \le t \le T \\
\beta(t-T) & T \le t \le T+T'
\end{cases}$$
Then you can verify that this defines an associative law, and the constant loop $\mathrm{cst}_{x_0} : [0,0] \to X$ is a unit.

Moore loops are good enough for some purposes, but they're also unsatisfying for some others: two different loops can have a different domain, and the concatenation of two loops has again a different domain. We're really interested in understanding $\Omega X$, so what can we do?

The answer lies in the [little intervals operad $\mathtt{D}_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad_theory). I refer you to [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1459369/10014) where I've written an explanation of what it is, and I will use the same notation; when $n=1$, $\mathtt{D}_1$ is called the little intervals operad because $D^1 = [-1,1] \cong I$ is just an interval; in what follows I will identify $D^1$ with $I$, it makes no difference.

A fundamental feature of $\Omega X$ is that it is an **algebra over the little intervals operad**. What does this mean? Let an operation in arity $r$:
$$c = (c_1, \dots, c_r) \in \mathtt{D}_1(r)$$
Recall that this means $c_i : I \to I$ is an affine embedding ($c_i(x) = t_i + \lambda_i x$, $0 < \lambda_i < 1$), and $c_i((0,1)) \cap c_j((0,1)) = \varnothing$ for $i \neq j$. Let also loops $\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_r \in \Omega X$. Then you can define $c(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_r) \in \Omega X$ by
$$c(\alpha_1, \dots, \alpha_r) : t \mapsto \begin{cases}
\alpha_i(u) & t = c_i(u) \text{ for some} i,u \\
x_0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

What does this look like? An element, say, $c \in \mathtt{D}_1(3)$ looks like this:

[image]

If you have three loops $\alpha, \beta, \gamma \in \Omega X$, then $c(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ is the loop that's equal to $\alpha$ (sped up to match the length) on the red part "1", $\beta$ on the blue part "2", and $\gamma$ on the green part "3". On the rest (the black part), it's equal to $x_0$. Since the endpoints of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ are all equal to $x_0$, this defines a continuous loop $c(\alpha, \beta, \gamma) \in \Omega$. Then one can check that this defines an algebra over $\mathtt{D}_1$.

So what does this have to do with associativity? Consider the element $m \in \mathtt{D}_1(2)$ given by embedding the first interval as the first half $[0,1/2]$ (so $c_1(t) = t/2$) and the second interval as the second half $[1/2,1]$ ($c_2(t) = (t+1)/2$). Then for $\alpha,\beta \in \Omega X$, $m(\alpha,\beta) = \beta \alpha$ is the concatenation of the two loops.

You have two different operations, $u = m(m, \operatorname{id})$ and $v = m(\operatorname{id}, m)$ in $\mathtt{D}_1(3)$, and $u(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = \gamma(\beta\alpha)$ while $v(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = (\gamma\beta)\alpha$. But now, there is a homotopy given by the structure of $\mathtt{D}_1$-algebra on $\Omega X$ between $u(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$ and $v(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) = (\gamma\beta)\alpha$! It's in fact a path in $\mathtt{D}_1(3)$, given by rescaling the intervals. And more generally if you have more loops, any parenthesization will be homotopic to any other (so say $((\alpha_1 \alpha_2) \alpha_3) \alpha_4 \sim (\alpha_1 \alpha_2) (\alpha_3 \alpha_4)$ through a homotopy that comes from the $\mathtt{D}_1$-algebra structure.

Such a structure is called a *strongly homotopy associative* algebra, or *$A_\infty$-algebra*, because you don't just know that $a(bc) \sim (ab)c$: you have a specific homotopy between the two (for all $a$, $b$, $c$), and these homotopies are all compatible with one another (meaning, for example, that if you have two homotopies $((ab)c)d \leadsto a(b(cd))$, then they are equal, similar to the coherence axioms for a [monoidal category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoidal_category)), and so on in higher arity. The [associahedra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associahedron) of Stasheff are combinatorial models for how these homotopies are compatible.

The recognition principle of Boardmann–Vogt and May also tells you that under technical conditions, if a space $Y$ can be endowed with the structure of a $\mathtt{D}_1$-algebra, then there is another space $X$ such that $Y \sim \Omega X$. So in that sense, the little interval operads exactly captures what it means to be a loop space.

This is the beginning of a very long story that's still being developed today. For example, an algebra over the little disks operad $\mathtt{D}_2$ is (by the recognition principle) essentially the same thing as a two-fold loop space $\Omega^2 X = \Omega(\Omega X)$. It's basically a strongly homotopy associative algebra with "one level" of commutativity, meaning there's a homotopy $ab \leadsto ba$ (but no it's not strongly homotopy commutative). Equivalently, it's the same thing as two strongly homotopy associative structure on the same space that are compatible with each other in the sense of the [Eckmann–Hilton argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eckmann%E2%80%93Hilton_argument). There are also applications for $\infty$-categories that you mention in your question, where the associativity axiom of a standard category is relaxed and instead only holds up to (coherent) homotopy.

Comment: The references are pretty much the same as for my [previous answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1459477/10014).