# Clarification regarding little n-discs operads

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, loop-spaces, operads

I am reading [the wiki page on operad theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operad_theory) and I am trying to figure out how exactly those "Little something" operads work which are mentioned there. Specifically, I am having a hard time, despite the verbal statements on the page, grasping what is really going on with the n-discs operads (you have an illustration on the right side of the page).
Could anyone help me out?

*(from the comments)* What I do not really understand is: 1) the precise manner in which the inner discs are constructed and inserted 2) whether or not those smaller discs within the unity disc have to somehow cover it all, or what kind of constraints apply...

By the way, maybe I should point out at the relation to this other topic I have a bounty on: [A question about Homotopy (Michael Harris's recent book)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449460/a-question-about-homotopy-michael-harriss-recent-book)

Comment: By the way, is there a way to copy and paste diagrams and drawings on the threads? That would make some of my questions easier, because I coould show some visualisations......

Comment: You can use LaTeX for diagrams (in particular there's the AMScd package available). For drawings, you can include pictures, so e.g. screenshots, scans...

Comment: I have tried to paste images (graphs, diagrams and the like) from my PC onto the messages, but it does not seem to work..... :(

Comment: [See this.](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#images)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I will concentrate on the little 2-discs operad $\newcommand{\DD}{\mathtt{D}_2}\DD$ (I think if you understand how it works, it shouldn't be a problem to understand the analog statements about the higher dimensional ones, or the little cubes operads).

Let 
$$D^2 = \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid x^2 + y^2 \le 1 \}$$
be the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$. An operation $c \in \DD(r)$ in arity $r$ is a collection $(c_1, \dots, c_r)$, where each $c_i$ is an embedding $c_i : D^2 \hookrightarrow D^2$ of the form
$$c_i(x,y) = (x_i + \lambda_i x, y_i + \lambda_i y)$$
(where of course $(x_i,y_i) \in D^2$, and $\lambda > 0$ is small enough such that $c_i(D^2) \subset D^2$). (Such an embedding is called a *rectilinear* embedding.) Furthermore, if $i \neq j$, we require that the image $\DeclareMathOperator{\itr}{int}\itr(D^2)$ of the interior of $D^2$ by $c_i$ and $c_j$ are disjoint; i.e. $$c_i(\itr(D^2)) \cap c_j(\itr(D^2)) = \varnothing;$$ this is equivalent to $d((x_i, y_i), (x_i, y_j)) \ge \lambda_i + \lambda_j$.

An element of $\DD(r)$ is advantageously represented like this:

[image: element of D_2(2)]

Here, you see an element of $\DD(2)$. There are two embeddings $c_1, c_2 : D^2 \to D^2$, and I've represented their images in the unit disk. (You can recover the embedding from the image, because the embedding only depends on the center of the disk and its radius.)

Now, what about the operadic composition? Suppose you're given $c \in \DD(r)$, and $d^1 \in \DD(k_1)$, ..., $d^r \in \DD(k_r)$, and you want to compute $c(d^1, \dots, d^r)$. As before, write $c = (c_1, \dots, c_r)$, and $d^i = (d^i_1, \dots, d^i_{k_i})$ (where the $c_i$ and $d^i_j$ are rectilinear embeddings $D^2 \to D^2$ satisfying the conditions about disjointness of interiors).

Then what happens is that $c_i \circ d^i_j$ is again a rectilinear embedding $D^2 \to D^2$. Besides, since $d^i_j(\itr(D^2)) \cap d^i_k(\itr(D^2)) = \varnothing$ for $j \neq k$, then they're still disjoint when composed by $c_i$. And since $c_i(\itr(D^2)) \cap c_{i'}(\itr(D^2)) = \varnothing$ for $i \neq i'$, then the images of the interior of $c_i \circ d^i_j(\itr(D^2)) \cap c_{i'} \circ d^{i'}_{j'}(\itr(D^2)) = \varnothing$. So finally, you get a sequence of rectilinear embeddings $D^2 \to D^2$
$$(c_1 \circ d^1_1, \dots, c_1 \circ d^1_{k_1}, c_2 \circ d^2_1, \dots, \dots, c_r \circ d^r_{k_r})$$
that satisfy the conditions on the images of interior. In other words, this is an element of $\DD(k_1 + \dots + k_r)$, and we define $c(d^1, \dots, d^r)$ to be that element. And then one checks that the operad axioms are satisfied.

Now how does this look like pictorially (the above definition isn't very easy to understand at first)? I find it easier to think of operads in term of *partial compositions*. Consider the special element $1 = (\operatorname{id}) \in \DD(1)$ (this is the identity of $D^2$, which is a rectilinear embedding, so it defines an element of $\DD$). Then if $c \in \DD(n)$ and $d \in \DD(m)$, one defines
$$c \circ_i d = c(1, \dots, 1, \underbrace{d}_{i}, 1, \dots, 1).$$
Basically, you "plug in" the operation $d$ in the $i$th position, and the identity in all the other positions. Then the composition in $\DD$ looks like this:

[image: example of composition]

I hope all this helps you.

#### References

- J. Michael Boardman and Rainer M. Vogt. *Homotopy invariant algebraic structure on topological spaces.* Lecture Notes in Mathematics 347. Springer, Berlin Heidelberg, 1973, pp. x+257. ISBN: 978-3-540-06479-4. DOI: [10.1007/BFb0068547](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0068547).
- J. Peter May. *The geometry of iterated loop spaces.* Lectures Notes in Mathematics 271. Springer-Verlag, Berlin, 1972, pp. viii+175. DOI: [10.1007/BFb0067491](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BFb0067491).
- Martin Markl, Steve Shnider, and Jim Stasheff. *Operads in algebra, topology and physics.* Mathematical Surveys and Monographs 96. American
  Mathematical Society, Providence, RI, 2002, pp. x+349. ISBN: 0-8218-2134-2.
- Jim Stasheff. “What is ... an operad?” In: *Notices Amer. Math. Soc.* 51.6 (2004), pp. 630–631. ISSN: 0002-9920. URL: http://www.ams.org/notices/200406/what-is.pdf
- Jean-Louis Loday and Bruno Vallette. Algebraic operads. Grundlehren der Mathematischen Wissenschaften [Fundamental Principles of Mathematical Sciences] 346. Springer, Heidelberg, 2012, pp. xxiv+634. ISBN: 978-3-642-30361-6. DOI: [10.1007/978-3-642-30362-3](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-30362-3). (For a more "algebraic" point of view on operads, they don't really speak much about the little disks operads I think.)
- Benoit Fresse. *Homotopy of Operads and Grothendieck–Teichmüller Groups.* Preprint. URL: http://math.univ-lille1.fr/~fresse/OperadHomotopyBook/. (Chapters 1-4 mostly.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will thoroughly reflect on it. Just one thing: could the elements be, for instance, stalks of a sheaf, or sheaves of a space themselves?

Comment: @JavierArias I have no idea (it's a strange question TBH), but I suspect the answer is "no". You're talking about the elements of $\mathtt{D}_2(r)$, right?

Comment: I am talking abut the possibility of having, say, instead on small discs within the unity disc, a stalk within a sheaf or sheaves within an interval of space...

Comment: Interesting post (+1). I am interested to know why disk operads arise in homotopy theory. Is there a "short" answer to that, consisting of maybe the essential keywords, so that it fits as a comment? Otherwise, I'd be happy if you can direct me to some kind of short survey too (I see you gave links to many literature on your answer above, but I'd like to know which one answers the question I have, as apparently there exists non homotopy theoretic viewpoint on operads too).

Comment: @BalarkaSen If you want keywords, it's "loop spaces" and "recognition principle". Under technical conditions, given $1 \le n \le \infty$, an $n$-fold loop space $\Omega^n X$ is the same thing, up to homotopy, as an algebra over $\mathtt{D}_n$. Of course the theory of operads has become much more than that since then, but I believe this is the starting point. See also [Why are operads useful?](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72490/why-are-operads-useful) on MO.

Comment: [cont.] see also [Algebra+Homotopy=Operad](http://arxiv.org/abs/1202.3245) for a treatment of operads from a more "algebraic" point of view of the homotopy theory behind operads.

Comment: Is I am asking some questions whic might sound weird is because I am trying to think about the use of these tools for possible modelling of social or natural phenomena, that is, as analytic tool for other disciplines.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi That's very interesting, thanks. I'll have a look at those links.